# Facebook comment box moderation stopped working

Tags: facebook, plugins

The comment moderation tool has stopped working for my Facebook comment box plug-in.  Prior to this problem, the comment moderation on my website had been working fine for many years, and I did not make any changes to my page.  But now, the link to the moderation tool has disappeared from the comment box on my website.  If I go to the moderation tool manually, then the new comments are not present in the list of comments in the moderation tool.  The old comments are still showing, but all the new comments that were posted after this problem started do not appear in the moderation tool.  (The new comments  still appear on my website.)
My website is at http://ar.vegnews.org/vegan.html
The moderation tool for my comments is at
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/123992434326906/

Thanks.

Edit:  The moderation tool has started working again.  It appears that this is no longer a problem.  Thanks.

Comment: I put your URL through the FB debug tool, at first it said meta data was missing, but after a re-scrape everything looks fine, app-id for moderation is set as 123992434326906

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Thanks CBroe.  The problem seems to now have gone away on its own.  Perhaps this is because you re-scraped the page on the FB debug tool.  Thanks.